# Android two applications need to start same service in their own respective processes

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service which provides data needed by two different applications.  I want each of these applications to bind to this service.  The applications can not share the same instance of this service, there has to be two instances,  because the service generates different data based what the application is doing.  The service should run locally within each application's process.

When the same service is started, does it run as a local service in the application that started it?

Comment: Put the `Service` in both applications, then, such as via a library module.